# Single hemisphere/ring orientation - Geography and SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, spatial, geography

I have been struggling with a basic polygon to be incorporated into SQL Server 2008 R2.

The following is working fine

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON (( 100 53, 100 -42.9, 210 -4, 210 53, 100 53 ))', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

While this one (just changing a latitude) is giving me the single hemisphere/ ring orientation error:

```
DECLARE @g geography;
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON (( 100 53, 100 -43, 210 -4, 210 53, 100 53 ))', 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
```

I tried several tools to fix that, play with the ring orientation (clockwise, counter-clockwise) with no result.

Your feedback would be welcome

Thanks

Sylvain

Comment: This isn't much help, but I can at least confirm that whilst the Polygon you're experiencing problems with spans both hemisphere's, at only 22.1% of the earth's surface it shouldn't throw an error.  Can I assume moving to SQL 2012 is not an option?

Comment: Thanks Jon for your answer. You're right. SQL 2012 is not an option for the time being. Stuck with SQL 2008 R2...